# Lipschitz Seminorms Associated to a Metric and Seminorms from Dirac Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

I am learning to work with spectral triples and given a spectral triple $(A, H, D)$ with representation $\pi$, a seminorm can be defined on $A$ via $L_D := \|[ D, \pi(f) ]\|_{B(H)}$.  View $A$ as $C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$.  With respect to this seminorm the spectral distance on $X$ can be defined by:

$$d_X(x,y) := \sup \{ |f(x) - f(y)| : L_D (f) \leq 1 \}.$$

Also, the Lipschitz seminorm associated to $d_X$ is given by:

$$L_{d_X}(f) := \sup \left\{ \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{d_X(x,y)}\  \middle | \  x,y \in X, x \neq y \right\}.$$

My question is: "Does $L_D$ always coincide with $L_{d_X}$ or does this depend on particular properties of the Dirac operator $D$?" I would begin by trying to show that $L_{d_X} (f) \leq L_D(f)$ for arbitrary $f \in A$ and vice versa, but I don't see how such arguments can be made without knowing more properties about the Dirac operator $D$.

Comment: You should state the definition of spectral triple you are using, since the exact conditions vary in the literature.

Comment: A spectral triple $(A, H, D)$ is given by a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$, a Hilbert space $H$ together with a unital, faithful representation $\pi$ of $A$ into $B(H)$ and an unbounded, self-adjoint operator $D$ on $H$ such that the set $\{a \in A \textit{ for which }[D,\pi(a)] \text{ is densely defined and extends to a bounded operator on } H \}$ is dense in $A$ and the operator $(I + D^2)^{-1}$ is compact.

Comment: Are you not also asking for $A$ to commutative, as otherwise you cannot get a sensible $X$. You could still define $X$ by the maximal ideals of $A$, but then $X$ could be empty for example and you have no hope for equality (only $L_{d_X}(f)≤ L_D(f)$ will hold then).

Comment: That is why I included the condition to view $A$ as $C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$ since all unital commutative $C^*$-algebras can be viewed as $C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$.  Why would $L_{d_X}(f) \leq L_{D}(f)$ hold generally, ie without asking for $A$ to be commutative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats true is that $L_{d_X}(f) ≤ L_{D}(f)$ for all $f\in A$ and if $A$ is commutative also $L_{d_X}(f)=0\implies L_{D}(f)=0$. I would guess that the inequality $L_{D}(f)≤L_{d_X}(f)$ is true if $A$ is commutative, but have not been able to prove it. However if $A$ is not commutative the object $X$ can be really dumb and it should be easy to find counter-examples to the second inequality. Now these considerations should clearly depend on the definition of a spectral triple, which I am not familiar with. I will write down what I think you are working with:

> A spectral triple is a triple $(A, H, D)$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space, $D$ is a densely define self-adjoint operator on $H$ and $A$ is a (here apparently commutative and unital) $C^*$ algebra together with a representation $\pi: A\to B(H)$.

First we check $L_D(f)=0$ $\iff$ $L_{d_X}(f)=0$, here the direction $\impliedby$ makes use of $A$ being commutative.

Suppose $L_D(f)=0$, then you get for all $x,y$ you get that either $f(x)=f(y)$ or $d_X(x,y)=\infty$, hence $\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d_X(x,y)}=0$ always and then $L_{d_X}(f)=0$. Now if $L_{d_X}(f)=0$ then whenever $f(x)\neq f(y)$ there must be some $g\in A$ with $L_D(g)=0$ and $g(x)\neq g(y)$. The $C^*$ sub-algebra of $A$ generated by all such $g$ then separate the points that $f$ separates and as such $f$ is a limit of such $g$ by Stone-Weierstraß. In particular you will get $[f, D]=0$ and $L_D(f)=0$.

Next the inequality $L_{d_X}≤ L_D$ follows from elementary considerations:

Let $f\in A$ with $L_D(f)\neq0$ and by rescaling assume $L_D(f)=1$. Then $d_X(x,y) ≥ |f(x)-f(y)|$ for any $x,y$ by the definition of $d_X$. Hence $\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d_X(x,y)}≤ 1$ for all $x,y$ and $L_{d_X}(f) ≤ L_D(f)$.

Comment: I just noticed the proof of the second inequality $L_D(f)≤ L_{d_X}(f)$ is not correct, as it is not clear if the inequality leading to the contradiction remains true under products or sums. I will try to rewrite this.

Comment: $n$x$n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ and $B(H)$ for a Hilbert space $H$ are all examples of noncommutative $C^*$-algebras so given the importance of these examples, I am not sure that corresponding $X$ for $C(X)$ would necessarily be "dumb."  Thank you very much for explaining why $L_{d_X}(f) \leq L_D(f)$ in general.  So the opposite inequality depends on the properties of the Dirac operator $D$?

Comment: $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb C)$ has no ideals, so its spectrum is empty, and $C(X)$ doesn't doesn't get dumber than $C(\emptyset)$! For your question, I managed to construct a counter-example to $L_D(f)≤L_{d_X}(f)$ by using a **non-symmetric** $D$. So while I believe that the inequality is still true in the commutative case, one needs to use some of the properties of $D$.

Comment: So properties of $D$ are not needed in the commutative case?  If so, then I would be very grateful if you could explain why as my $A$ does happen to be commutative and unital.

Comment: No, what I said was that I think the remaining inequality $L_D(f)≤ L_{d_X}(f)$ is true for $A$ commutative, but don't have a proof. The results proven in the answer do not need any properties of $D$ (the only thing needed is that $L_D$ is continuous semi-norm on $C(X)$, but where it comes from is irrelevant). The proof of the missing inequality $L_D ≤ L_{d_X}$ (if it is true!) will need some of the properties of $D$, as one can construct simple counter-examples to the inequality by taking non-symmetric $D$. So if the inequality is true, we will need to use symmetry for example at some point.

Comment: But why does $A$ commutative not require the properties of $D$ to get $L_D(f) \leq L_{d_X}(f)$?

Comment: No, let me repeat: $L_{d_X}≤ L_D$ is the inequality that does not require properties of $D$ (and also doesn't require $A$ to be commutative or unital). The inequality $L_D ≤ L_{d_X}$ is not proven, and if it is true it **will** need properties of $D$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and explanations!